# How to check if an element with id having the word 'date' exists using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to use datetimepicker for any input elements whose ID contain the word `'date'`.

Basically, I want something link this:

```
$("where id has word 'date'").each(function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker({
        formatTime:'H:i:s',
        formatDate:'Y-m-d',
        dayOfWeekStart : 1,
        lang:'en',
        disabledDates:['1986/01/08','1986/01/09','1986/01/10'],
        startDate:  '<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>'
    });
});
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) Selector from jquery such as.

```
$("[id*='date']").each(function(){
    $(this).datetimepicker({
                    formatTime:'H:i:s',
                    formatDate:'Y-m-d',
                    dayOfWeekStart : 1,
                    lang:'en',
                    disabledDates:['1986/01/08','1986/01/09','1986/01/10'],
                    startDate:  '<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>'
                });
});
```

Or more appropriatly just add a custom class for this and use the class selector.

**I must add**

You wont need to fire the `each` iterator for this unless there is something different in the options for each `datetimepicker`

```
$("[id*='date']").datetimepicker({
                    formatTime:'H:i:s',
                    formatDate:'Y-m-d',
                    dayOfWeekStart : 1,
                    lang:'en',
                    disabledDates:['1986/01/08','1986/01/09','1986/01/10'],
                    startDate:  '<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>'
                });
```

Will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$( "input[id*='date']" ).each(function(){..});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `id*` attribute selector

```
$('[id*=date]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery "contains" selector:

`$('input[id*=date]')`